# Serialization error when on starting Flink App

Tags: serialization, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a Flink app which keeps erroring out with this error.

```
com.org.ads.audience.traffic.MyClass@6eaa21d8 is not serializable. The object probably contains or references non serializable fields.
        org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:140)
        org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:115)
        org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.clean(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1558)
        org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream.clean(DataStream.java:185)
        org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream.flatMap(DataStream.java:611
```

Its proving really hard to track why this class is not serializable. I've made sure that `MyClass` and all other classes that it references are `Serializable` and have default constructors. How can I debug this further? I tried adding `-Dsun.io.serialization.extendedDebugInfo=true` to the command line but it does not seem to be providing me any more information.
I am running in yarn cluster mode.

Comment: I have some questions... What type of function is Myclass used in? Have you tried to instantiate the myclass object as a transient?

Comment: Hi - `MyClass` implements `FlatMapFunction`. And yes! I was able to get past this error by making the object transient :) Wondering if this affects performance / is the right thing to do?

Comment: one other thing - even despite marking some instance variables of `MyClass` as transient, I had to explication add `MyClass implements Serializable` for my Flink app to not error out. This seems weird.

Answer (score 0):

One of my classes was using JDBC's `BasicDataSource` which contains non serializable elements. I had to mark that as `transient` to be able to serialize.

Comment: Why are you using a JDBC BasicDataSource ? Your data should come from a Flink flow instead of an external data source.

Comment: I am reading events from Kafka, and I need to join them with some (mostly static) data in mysql. I'm doing this in a `FlatMap` function.

Comment: something like this https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/dev/stream/operators/asyncio.html, except I am not currently doing any async io.